# Returning new state of persisted object to the view

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, controller

In my current spring project, the insert and update events are handled in my controller by this methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value="cadastra", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public String cadastra(@ModelAttribute("object") E object, BindingResult result, @RequestParam(value="file", required=false) MultipartFile file, @RequestParam(value="icone", required=false) MultipartFile icone, @RequestParam(value="screenshot", required=false) MultipartFile screenshot[]) throws Exception {
    if (serv.cadastra(object, file, icone, screenshot) != null)
        return "";
    else
        throw new Exception();
}

@RequestMapping(value="altera", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public String altera(@ModelAttribute("object") E object, BindingResult result, @RequestParam(value="file", required=false) MultipartFile file, @RequestParam(value="icone", required=false) MultipartFile icone, @RequestParam(value="screenshot", required=false) MultipartFile screenshot[]) throws Exception {
    if (serv.altera(object, file, icone, screenshot) != null)
        return "";
    else
        throw new Exception();
}
```

and in service class by this methods:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'cadastra_'+#this.this.name)")
@Transactional
public E cadastra(E e, MultipartFile file, MultipartFile icone, MultipartFile[] screenshot) {
    return dao.persist(e);
}

@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'altera_'+#this.this.name)")
@Transactional
public E altera(E e, MultipartFile file, MultipartFile icone, MultipartFile[] screenshot) {
    return dao.merge(e);
}
```

I want that my controller return to the view, instead a empty string, the data saved in the database, to allow me update some fields in the view with this information, ising jquery. One of the codes that will use this information is this:

```
        $(".permissao").each(function(){
            var form = this;
            var type = $(form).data("type");
            $(form).ajaxForm(function(data){
                if(data == "") {
                    $(form).find(".alert-success").find(".alert-text").text("Solicitação efetuada com sucesso");
                    $(form).find(".alert-success").show();
                    if(type == "cadastra") {
                        console.log('cadastrado');
                        var id = 0;
                        var nome = "...";
                        var group = $('<div class="input-group" id="grupo_'+id+'">');
                        group.append('<span class="input-group-addon"></span>');
                        group.append('<input type="text" class="form-control" disabled="disabled" value="'+nome+'">');
                        group.append('<span class="input-group-btn"></span>');
                        $(".column").append(group);
                        add_input(id, 'plus');
                    }
                    if(type == "altera") {
                        console.log("alterado");
                        var id = 0;
                        $("#detail-"+id).empty();
                    }
                    if(type == "remove") {
                        console.log('removido');
                        var id = $(form).find("input[name='id']").val();
                        $("#grupo_"+id).remove();
                        $("#altera-"+id).remove();
                        $("#remove-"+id).remove();
                        $("#detail-"+id).remove();
                    }
                } else {
                    var $temp  = $('<div/>', {html:data});
                    $(form).find(".alert-danger").find(".alert-text").text( $temp.remove('head').html() );
                    $(form).find(".alert-danger").show();
                }
            });
        });
```

where the variables `id` and `nome` above should receive the respective values od the fields with same name in the object.

Anyone can point me a direction to do this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? If you want your controller to return the data then you can surely do the by changing `return "";` to return what you want. I still find your question confusing.

Comment: @DarshanLila for instance, if I return an object of a class, how I do access the desired member-functions in my jquery code, to read the values of `id` and `nome` attributes?

Comment: You can use ajax response, if you are making an ajax call. When you get the response you can extract values out of it like a normal object(`object.field`).

Comment: @DarshanLila see the jquery code I posted.